# Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the hadoop binary

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

Recently I have installed canopy and spark in my system. When i ran pyspark command in c:\spark path in canopy command prompt,  I'm getting this error, but winutils was present in that path. I'm new to this I don't know how to solve this. I searched in online but failed to understand. Can anyone help me with this issue.

Comment: You need to set the variable `HADOOP_HOME` to something like 
 `C:\Hadoop\` and then put `winutils.exe` under 
 `C:\Hadoop\bin\winutils.exe`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to follow the next steps:

```
1. Download winutils.exe
2. Create folder, say C:\winutils\bin
3. Copy winutils.exe inside C:\winutils\bin
4. Set environment variable HADOOP_HOME to C:\winutils
```

Comment: where do I get winutils.exe?